# Slow loading of pictures - using picaso and Firebase Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I created a profile for a user and i've got one problem:
The loading is slow - due to every pic is 4mb and it takes about 20 sec to load,
I need some help about image compression/methods to reduce data and make the program download the img and put it into the profile faster.

Im using android studio and java

this is my code:
Here im adding to the user some information

```
private void sendUserData() {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myref = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseAuth.getUid());
    userProfile user = new userProfile(Sphone, Semail, name);// simple object  get and set 
    myref.setValue(user);
    UpdateUserInfo(name, pickedImgUri, firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser());


}
```

Here its uploading the image

```
private void UpdateUserInfo(final String name, Uri pickedimguri, final FirebaseUser currnetUser) {

    StorageReference mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("users_photos");
    final StorageReference imagefilepath = mStorageReference.child(pickedimguri.getLastPathSegment());
    imagefilepath.putFile(pickedimguri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            imagefilepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                            .setDisplayName(name)
                            .setPhotoUri(uri)
                            .build();
                    currnetUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                        showMessage("Register complete");
                                    }
                                }
                           });
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the loading code to the user profile after creating it and entering the main screen:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    name = getView().findViewById(R.id.textView);
    profilepic = getView().findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    final String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    final DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    final DatabaseReference uidRef = rootRef.child(uid);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String email = dataSnapshot.child("email").getValue(String.class);
            String nameE = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            String phone = dataSnapshot.child("phone").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", nameE + ", " + email + ", " + phone);
            name.setText("Welcome " + nameE);
            Picasso.get().load(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhotoUrl().toString()).into(profilepic);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
        }
    };
    uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try compressing your images - 4mb each image will add up very quickly

Comment: And what is the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: posted example as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of compressing an image for firebase storage. This is the method I'm using, and it reduces images between 2-4mb down to <300kb. JPEG is a lossy format and I use a level of 75 for compression, which still retains most of the detail in an image.

```
//Start with URI of image
if (uri != null) {
            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, baos);
            byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
            StorageReference reference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("whatever folder you place the images in/" + name_of_image + ".jpg");
            UploadTask uploadTask = reference.putBytes(bytes);

            uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ill try it

Comment: Works like a charm!